# How to create and send a SOAP request with the help of WSDL and receive SOAP response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I am very new to WCF. I want to send a SOAP request to a webservice and receive response from the same. The WSDL is: http://content.domain.com/ContentService?wsdl. I have added this wsdl to ServiceReference. What's next ?

SOAP request I need to build should be look like-

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:con="http://content.domain.com" xmlns:api="http://api.content.domain.com">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
<con:get1>
<con:in0>
<api:AID>89575</api:AID>
<api:clientLoginID>abc</api:clientLoginID>
<api:domain>en</api:domain>
</con:in0>
</con:get1>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There will be a xml response to this request which I need to parse and get the values from it. How can I achieve this in c#?

Comment: You don't need to manually build the SOAP request.  You said you added the service - are you able to reach it with the client?

Comment: It looks like you already got an answer on this thread - http://forums.asp.net/t/1900780.aspx/1?How+to+create+a+SOAP+request+with+the+help+of+WSDL+and+receive+SOAP+response+  Was there something in the answer that you didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Read the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730144.aspx)

```
//Step 1: Create an instance of the WCF proxy.
CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();

// Step 2: Call the service operations.
// Call the Add service operation.
double value1 = 100.00D;
double value2 = 15.99D;
double result = client.Add(value1, value2);
```